Collapse rows by value in non null column
I have my input dataframe in this format:
id  col_a   col_b   col_c  col_d
1   3.2     NaN     NaN    a
1   NaN     88.0    NaN    NaN
1   NaN     NaN     type1  NaN
2   4.1     NaN     NaN    NaN
2   NaN     NaN     type3  NaN
2   NaN     123.0   NaN    b
3   8.0     NaN     NaN    c
3   NaN     65.0    NaN    NaN
3   NaN     NaN     type2  NaN

There are 2 or 3 rows for each id. The value of the other columns is contained in only one of the 3 rows. The remaining rows for the same column in rows the same id will contain NaN
I want the output to be in this format:
id  col_a   col_b   col_c    col_d
1   3.2     88      type1    a  
2   4.1     123     type3    b
3   8.0     65      type2    c

How do I do this in pandas?

df.groupby('id', as_index=False).first()
